# How to remove duplicate rows using CTE?

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to remove duplicate rows from my table. So that I have used `ROW_NUMBER()` function in order to find the duplicate values. After that I wanted to add **WHERE** claues to my query and so that I modify my query and used "CTE" but it gives me an error

> ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

This is the query which runs successfully for my use case :

```
WITH RowNumCTE as
(
 SELECT ID,parcelid,propertyaddress,saledate,saleprice,legalreference,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER
         ( PARTITION BY parcelid,propertyaddress,saledate,saleprice,legalreference 
               ORDER BY id ) AS rn
    FROM housedata
)
SELECT *
  FROM RowNumCTE
```

Comment: doesn't adding `where rn = 1` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete duplicates:

```
delete housedata where rowid in
       ( select lead(rowid) over (partition by parcelid, propertyaddress, saledate, saleprice, legalreference order by id)
         from   housedata );
```

To delete duplicates using a CTE:

```
delete housedata where id in
       ( with cte as
              ( select id
                     , row_number() over(partition by parcelid, propertyaddress, saledate, saleprice, legalreference order by id) as rn
                from   housedata )
         select id from cte
         where  rn > 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need

```
BEGIN
  FOR d IN
  (    
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
          ( PARTITION BY parcelid,propertyaddress,saledate,saleprice,legalreference 
                ORDER BY id ) AS rn, 
           h.*
      FROM housedata h
  )
  LOOP
    IF d.rn > 1 THEN
       DELETE housedata WHERE id = d.id; 
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT; 
END;    
/
```

considering those five columns compose the grouping criteria for the desired deletion and `id` is a primary key column.

Comment: Thank you. But this gives me an PL/SQL compilation error

Comment: Hi @MohammadLitonHossain , what error do you get ?

Comment: ORA-06550: line 13, column 5:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06550: line 12, column 8:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 14, column 7:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LOOP" when expecting one of the following:

   if
ORA-06550: line 16, column 8:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static
   member constructor map
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

Comment: BEGIN
  FOR d IN
  (    
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
          ( PARTITION BY parcelid,propertysplitaddress,saleprice,legalreference 
                ORDER BY id ) AS rn, 
           h.*
      FROM housedata h
  )
  LOOP
    IF d.rn > 1 THEN
       DELETE FROM housedata WHERE id = d.id 
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT; 
END;    I have already done it but did not work

Comment: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static
   member constructor map
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

Comment: then, please make sure about the semi-colons whether they're correctly stated @MohammadLitonHossain

Comment: I have edited your question(I've fixed the CTE while you don't need a CTE for the deletion code), have a look at that please @MohammadLitonHossain

Comment: @MohammadLitonHossain you are missing a semicolon in `WHERE id = d.id END IF;`

Answer (score 0):

--Remove Duplciates[SKR]

--Option A:

```
select * 
--delete t
from(
    select rowNumber=row_number() over (partition by SomeKey order by SomeKey), SomeKey from YourTable m 
)t where rowNumber > 1;
```

--Option B:

```
with cte as (
    select rowNumber=row_number() over (partition by SomeKey order by SomeKey), SomeKey from YourTable m 
) 
--delete from cte where rowNumber > 1
select * from cte where rowNumber > 1
```